# How do I respec mid-game in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I've played some fallout with an average all-rounder character to get to know the game and see which play-style I like. Now I would like to specialize, but I don't really have much desire/spare time to redo all the story that I've completed so far starting with a new character, so I'd like to respec.
Effectively, I would like to reallocate SPECIALs and perks picked for level-ups.

Note, I'm fine with cheating this, if its the only option.

Comment: Respec Holotape mod should work for your needs
http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/14977/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible without cheating. With cheating you can choose your own perk levels though.

> Type tilde (~) key to bring up the console.
>   Then type player.setav variable amount
>
> variable would be one of these:
>
> strength
>
> perception
>
> endurance
>
> charisma
>
> intelligence
>
> agility
>
> luck

Then the number you would like that perk to have.
[Source: Steam forums](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136903494337/)

It is also possible to modify a value by a certain amount.
for that use `player.modav`, but beware that this will NOT affect the perk chart whereas `setav` will.

[Complete list of console commands](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands)
[Complete list of adjustable stats, including perks](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands#Character_variables)

Comment: Would it be **perc**, or **perk**?

Comment: It's perception.

Comment: For those who don't know yet: There is no level cap in Fallout 4, so you could get all the perks and max your SPECIAL if you play long enough. That's the reason why you can't respec without console commands. Once you're high level enough, respec becomes obsolete.

Comment: This says how to reallocate special points, what about perks?

Comment: I have added a list of all adjustable stats, including perks.

Comment: @Nolonar Fair point, but unless you're somehow earning all those levels without triggering any quests or non-combat NPC interactions, there are several spots in the game where a low SPECIAL stat can limit your gameplay options. After several hours in my first playthrough, I actually wiped and re-built my character with 10 Charisma to start specifically because of this - AFAICT, Charisma checks are the only non-repeatable barriers that can't be worked around with player skill.

Comment: Interesting.  This is one of the first games where you actually get pretty huge advantage with high CHARISMA.  This has almost always been my dump stat in other Fallout games.